# Is there a \ding symbol for a house?

Tags: symbols

Is there a \ding symbol for a house? I need it for my CV, but can't find it. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The first place to check is [symbols-a4](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) or [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). I don't see one in the `pifont` package (`\ding{<num>}`), but other symbol fonts exist.

Comment: `\tikz \draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt]
(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);` - Till Tantau

Answer (score 50, accepted):

We can use direct `\pdfliteral`. For example:

```
\def\house{\hbox{\kern3pt \vbox to13pt{}% 
   \pdfliteral{q 0 0 m 0 5 l 5 10 l 10 5 l 10 0 l 7 0 l 7 5 l 3 5 l 3 0 l f
               1 j 1 J -2 5 m 5 12 l 12 5 l S Q }%
   \kern 13pt}}

House: \house.

\end
```

[image: house]

Comment: Basic knowledge :)

Comment: @wipet Could you please provide a source to learn more about those pdf literals?

Comment: @HenriMenke The main reference is PDF reference manual from Adobe, of course. But we need to know only very small subset of this knowledge in order to draw simple graphics. This was summarized in my article "Simple graphics in PDF by PDF primitives" http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/bulletin/pdfgrafika.pdf (but it is only in Czech language, sorry).

Comment: @wipet Unfortunately I don't speak Czech.  But thank you very much for this resource.  Maybe Google Translate can help me.

Comment: This looks hilariously good.

Answer (score 34):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\house}[2]{{\fontspec{#1}\symbol{"#2}}}

\begin{document}
    Lamentable class:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{26FA}
    \house{quivira.otf}{26FA}

    Lower class:
    \house{code2000.ttf}{2302}
    \house{symbola.ttf}{2302}
    \house{Linux Libertine O}{2302}
    \house{quivira.otf}{2302}
    \house{freeserif.ttf}{2302}

    Middle class:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3E0}
    \house{quivira.otf}{1F3E0}

    Upper class:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3E1}
    \house{quivira.otf}{1F3E1}

    Property owner:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3D8}

    Business:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3E2}
    \house{quivira.otf}{1F3E2}

    Dandy:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3DB}
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3EF}

    King:
    \house{symbola.ttf}{1F3F0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to put those icons at LyX but it's give an error. Do you know why? how can I use those icons at LyX? Thank you!

Comment: @Yoar What error? I can't guess. Are you compiling with Lua- or XeLaTeX? Please consider asking a new question if this is not treated any where on this site.

Answer (score 33):

Well, I guess I'll join the bandwagon too. This solution uses the [`fontawesome`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) package/symbol font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
Test home symbol: \faHome
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that it does not compile with pdftex?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner thanks, at the time the answer was written, `fontawesome` only supported OTF-capable engines. Since then, the situation has changed. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 11):

This is the closest I can think of.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[alpine]{ifsym}
\begin{document}
\Hut
\end{document}
```

[image: hut]

Comment: `\HalfFilledHut\FilledHut\Village\Tent`

Answer (score 9):

The easiest thing to do is to google "house icon" images, which leads you to a page like http://fashionnow.website/house-icon-png/, download an image or two, and include them as graphics in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Here are some icons:
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{Home_Icon}
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{house_Icon}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Build your own house

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
My home 
\(\rlap{$\widehat{\,\ \ \ \ }$}{\,\tiny
\fboxsep0pt\fbox{$\bigsqcap^{_\boxplus^{}
\kern-1pt}$}\,}^{^{^{\!\!\!\!\!\wr}}}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like very much your house....spectacular. 

Answer (score 2):

fontawesome can be used in plain tex:

```
\font\aw=FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm
Home symbol: \aw{\char153}
\bye
```

Comment: Using plain tex this does indeed give a house icon so it does answer the question. The OP is probably after a LaTeX solution but at this we can only since no [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) was supplied.

Answer (score 2):

With `stix` package there is a specific symbol called `\house`. I added an MWE for this symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
$\house$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

LuaLaTeX now supports emoji.

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{emoji}
\setemojifont{NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf}

\begin{document}

Our house~\emoji{house} in the middle of the street.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Very nice also this approach. My sincere compliments.

Answer (score 0):

A alternate solution working with `pdflatex` (hence without `fontspec`) can use the Twitter's open source emoticons as pictures, as provided by the [`twemojis`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/twemojis) package. With it, you can simply use `\twemoji{house}`  in any text context.

The macro `\twemoji` is based on `\includegraphics` and accepts the related options.
The documentation provide several alternatives like, e.g
`\twemoji{house with garden}`.

It also gives some indications about the CC-BY licence of theses pictures if you intent to use them out of personal use.