# having a house icon in a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, tikz-styles

I want to have a house icon in a tikz figure where I can say exactly where to put a house icon there and I am wondering whether I can have one of [these fancy icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skr8w.png) from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234797/is-there-a-ding-symbol-for-a-house/234807), for instance, in the node with specific scaling parameter for it?

Comment: Yes, you can. What makes you think you couldn't?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat is it possible to bring these house shapes not just latex symbols in the `tikz` structure?

Comment: What do you mean by that: "to bring these house shapes not just latex symbols"? If you mean whether you can include external graphics, the answer is yes.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat would you mind add also an example?

Comment: You can add e.g. `\node at (6,7) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{example-image-duck}};` to my example below. Just replace `example-image-duck` by the name of a graphics that shows a house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the house is not some `tikzpicture`, which would mean that you nest `tikzpicture`s, you can just put it in a node. You can also include external graphics.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[help lines] grid ++ (10,10);
 \node[scale=2] at (3,4) {\faHome};
 \node at (6,7) {\includegraphics[width=8mm]{example-image-duck}};
 \begin{scope}[shift={(5,5)}]
  \clip(-0.5,-0.5) -- (-0.5,0.2)  -- (-0.6,0.2) -- (0,0.5) -- 
   (0.6,0.2) --  (0.5,0.2) |- cycle;
  \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=16mm]{example-image-duck}};
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the well-behaved duck that stays at home. :-)

Comment: @frougon There is also no pineapple on the pizza, so all good.